# Parsing html links by html agility pack in c#

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio-2013, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I'm new in C#. I need to pars link from category and subcategory.

I have a category, but when i try to take subcategory i have error:

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

My code:

```
foreach (var link in xpathLinks)
        {

                okno.Text += link.Attributes["href"].Value + "\n";
                string doc2 = HtmlPage.DownloadString("htmlPage" + link.
                    Attributes["href"].Value);
                dokument2.LoadHtml(doc2);
                HtmlNodeCollection xpathLinks2 = dokument2.DocumentNode.
                    SelectNodes("//ul[@class='category-nav']//li//a");
                foreach (var Link in xpathLinks2)
                {
                    okno.Text += Link.Attributes["href"].Value + "\n";
                }

            }
        }
```

I'm usin HtmlAgilityPack. The error is in xpathLinks2.

Comment: [What is a `NullReferenceException` and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: `NullReferenceException` is a common situation for beginner programmers. The link provided should help you understand the problem. Then use the debugger to find what/where/when you have a variable that is `null`.

Comment: Yes, but xpathLinks2 is taking value from website, and i can't give there any value.

Comment: Question is not yet good fit for SO - please consider fixing following issues with the post: missing data necessary to demonstrate the problem, missing steps already taken to investigate NRE. Also make sure to read some basic XPath manual - i.e. some can be found by https://www.bing.com/search?q=msdn+xpath search.

Comment: OK, I finally find the problem. One of category has another class, and there was a problem. Thanks for help. :D